# The image of the upper-half-plane under $f(z)=1/(z+\alpha)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $\bar{\mathbb{H}}=\{ x+iy|y\geq 0\}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{H}$. what is $f(\bar{\mathbb{H}})$ when $f=1/(z+\alpha)$?

I know that under $1/z$,$\bar{\mathbb{H}}$ is mapped onto the unit circle. But I can't obtain the same thing for $1/(z+\alpha)$.

Comment: The image under 1/z is the lower halfplane, not the unit disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha = a+ib $ with $b > 0$. Then
$$ 
f(z) = \frac{1}{z+ \alpha} = \frac 1 b\frac{1}{(z+a)/b+i}
$$
is the composition of the maps
$$
 z \mapsto (z+a)/b \, , \, z \mapsto \frac{1}{z+i} \, ,
 \, z \mapsto z/b \, .
$$

The first map maps $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$ onto itself.

The image of $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$ under the second map $z \mapsto 1/(z+i)$ can be determined by computing the image of three points on the boundary:
$$
 0 \mapsto -i \, , \, 1 \mapsto \frac 12 - \frac i 2 \, , \, \infty \mapsto 0 \, .
$$
That image is a disk with center $-i/2$ and radius $1/2$.

Finally $z \mapsto z/b$ maps that disk to the disk with center $-i/(2b)$ and radius $1/(2b)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Got it completely.